# Assign default values in constructor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

Is there any way to define default values for an object proporties in the constructor?  I have a constructor that recives multiple parameters and if the params are not given I want to have some default values. For now I have this approach:

```
class Item{
    
    constructor(id, name, um, unitPrice, quantity, discounts, taxes){
    this.id = id || -1,
    this.name = name || 'n/a',
    this.um = um || new UnitOfMeasurment(),
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice || 0,
    this.quantity = quantity || 0,
    this.discounts = discounts || [],
    this.taxes = taxes || []
    }
    
}


function UnitOfMeasurment(id, name) {
    this.id = id || -1;
    this.name = name || 'n/a';
}
```

It seems ok, but if I create a new item with only the last 3 params for example, then all of them will assiged  wrong.

Comment: show an example for how you assign only with the last three parameters

Comment: You cannot just pass three arguments and expect the function to know that those should be assigned to the last three parameters. You'd have to pass `undefined` for any other parameter. However, with so many arguments it's probably better to pass a configuration object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give an object, that way you can avoid parameters you don't need.

```js
...
constructor({
  id = -1, 
  name = 'n/a', 
  um = new UnitOfMeasurment(), 
  unitPrice = 0, 
  quantity, 
  discounts, 
  taxes
})
...
```

```js
new Item({
  name, 
  taxes
});
```

Comment: If you add `... = {}` after the object pattern, the constructor can also be called without argument.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick. They're called default parameters.

```
class Item{
    
    constructor(id, name, um, unitPrice, quantity = 0, discounts = [], taxes = []){
    this.id = id || -1,
    this.name = name || 'n/a',
    this.um = um || new UnitOfMeasurment(),
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice || 0,
    this.quantity = quantity,
    this.discounts = discounts,
    this.taxes = taxes
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what he meant